# how to make wait javascript to finish all functions before return result

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

```
output = true;

if($("#password-field").css('display') != 'none') {
    if(!($("#verificationCode").val())) {
        output = false;
        $("#code-error").html("required");
    }   

    var codeverify =  function(){

    var code = document.getElementById("verificationCode").value;
    coderesult
        .confirm(code)
        .then( function(result) {
            if (result.user.uid) {
                let phoneNumber =  result.user.phoneNumber;
                //alert(output);
                 alert("Verification done");
                console.log(phoneNumber);

            } else {
                alert(output);
                $("#code-error").html("no user");
                  output = false;
            }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            output = false;
            $("#code-error").html("wrong");
            alert(error.message);
        });

        }();

}

return output;
```

When i run this code everything works fine. but before checking the codeverify function it return the output to true even if the codeverify() function returns false

PS. I am using wizard form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: sorry i am not good in javascript. and i tried this but i don't know what i mistake i make

Comment: You should read more about promises otherwise even if someone convert this function to a promise for you, you would still have to handle it in the main function. So I would suggest read a bit about promises, things would make more sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to how you write JavaScript code, I found that usually when to get to a point where my procedures are out of sync it means that I have done something wrong in previous steps. This is usually only fixed by refactoring.

Remember JavaScript does not behave the same as other languages.

What I can see from your procedure is that you are trying to do many things in one go.

Although I do not have a solution I have a suggestion, consider each action that you want your procedure to execute. Declare a separate function for each of these steps, even if your function only has one line to execute.

If there are dependencies make sure they can be resolved by parameterization.

And lastly, think pure functions. Try and structure every function to receive something and return something.

Another tip that I can give is, write your procedure to select and hold elements in variables until they are required. Consider what elements are required in execution, which of those are in the dom when execution starts and set them to variables before you start executing, then during execution if elements are added that are maybe required for later select them immediately after they are placed in the dom, this means that as your procedure executes all the ingredients are available to do whatever must be done they don't have to go find what they need on the fly.

Good Luck and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Your `coderesult.confirm(code)` using promise(`then` & `catch`) so i assume it is asynchronous. You need to google yourself to learn what is async

One important thing of JS behavior is JS always process the rest of the code if there is a async function in between.

Sample:

```js
console.log(1)
setTimeout(()=>{
  console.log(2,"i suppose at position 2 but i'm at the last. This is because setTimeout is async function")
},1000) 
console.log(3)
```

In your case, your `codeverify` function has async code (`.confirm()`) in between, so JS will process the code after `codeverify` (`return output`)until `codeverify` is fully completed.

Since your `output` was set at `true` since the beginning, it will return `true` from the last row of code `return output` before your `codeverify` completed, this is why you always get `true`. If you change the first row `output = undefined`, i believe you will see `undefined` result.

To solve this, one of the way is you can wrap the entire `codeverify` as `Promise`.

```
function codeverify(){
   return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      var code = document.getElementById("verificationCode").value;
        coderesult.confirm(code).then( function(result) {
            if (result.user.uid) {
                let phoneNumber =  result.user.phoneNumber;
                //alert(output);
                alert("Verification done");
                console.log(phoneNumber);
                output = true
                resolve(output)

            } else {
                alert(output);
                $("#code-error").html("no user");
                output = false;
                resolve(output)
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            output = false;
            $("#code-error").html("wrong");
            alert(error.message);
            reject(output) //you can reject(error.message) so you can pass error message back.
        });
   })
}
```

You can execute the function like this:

```
codeverify().then(successData=>{
   console.log(successData) //from what you resolve
}).catch(failedData=>{
   console.log(failedData) //from what you reject
})
```

Lastly, take some time to study what is Asynchronous and What Promise to do with Async because it is everywhere in JS.

Comment: Hi all i am confused with the async and promise function. But i found one simple solution for time being . Thanks all for the support.